# Getting "cannot write mode P as JPEG" while operating on JPG image

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library

I am trying to resize some images, most of which are JPG. But in a few images, I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "image_operation_new.py", line 168, in modifyImage
    tempImage.save(finalName);
  File "/Users/kshitiz/.virtualenvs/django_project/lib/python2.7/site-     packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1465, in save
   save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "/Users/kshitiz/.virtualenvs/django_project/lib/python2.7/site-   packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line 455, in _save
    raise IOError("cannot write mode %s as JPEG" % im.mode)
IOError: cannot write mode P as JPEG
```

I am not changing the image type and I'm using the pillow library. My OS is Mac OS X. How can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

You need to convert the image to RGB mode.

```
Image.open('old.jpeg').convert('RGB').save('new.jpeg')
```

Comment: I tried this on a .png file and the resulting .jpg was more than 5 times larger.

Comment: @Bentley4 PNG can compress certain types of images much better than JPEG

Comment: @Bentley4 you can convert it back to `P` after resampling

Answer (score 34):

This answer is quite old, however, I thought I will put a better way to do the same by checking for the mode before doing the conversion:

```
if img.mode != 'RGB':
    img = img.convert('RGB')
```

This is required to save your image in JPEG format.

Comment: This, in combination with the current top-voted answer, got my project back on track, thank you!

Answer (score 10):

summary [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48206051/image-conversion-cannot-write-mode-rgba-as-jpeg) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248405/cannot-write-mode-rgba-as-jpeg/48248432):

- backgroud

  - `JPG` not support `alpha = transparency`
  - `RGBA`, `P` has `alpha = transparency`

    - `RGBA`= `Red Green Blue Alpha`
- result

  - `cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG`
  - `cannot write mode P as JPEG`
- solution

  - before save to JPG, discard `alpha = transparency`

    - such as: convert `Image` to `RGB`
  - then save to `JPG`
- your code

```py
if im.mode == "JPEG":
    im.save("xxx.jpg")
    # in most case, resulting jpg file is resized small one
elif rgba_or_p_im.mode in ["RGBA", "P"]:
    rgb_im = rgba_or_p_im.convert("RGB")
    rgb_im.save("xxx.jpg")
    # some minor case, resulting jpg file is larger one, should meet your expectation
```

- do more for you:

about resize imgae file, I have implement a function, for your refer:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
cfgDefaultImageResample = Image.BICUBIC # Image.LANCZOS

def resizeImage(inputImage,
                newSize,
                resample=cfgDefaultImageResample,
                outputFormat=None,
                outputImageFile=None
                ):
    """
        resize input image
        resize normally means become smaller, reduce size
    :param inputImage: image file object(fp) / filename / binary bytes
    :param newSize: (width, height)
    :param resample: PIL.Image.NEAREST, PIL.Image.BILINEAR, PIL.Image.BICUBIC, or PIL.Image.LANCZOS
        https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.thumbnail
    :param outputFormat: PNG/JPEG/BMP/GIF/TIFF/WebP/..., more refer:
        https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html
        if input image is filename with suffix, can omit this -> will infer from filename suffix
    :param outputImageFile: output image file filename
    :return:
        input image file filename: output resized image to outputImageFile
        input image binary bytes: resized image binary bytes
    """
    openableImage = None
    if isinstance(inputImage, str):
        openableImage = inputImage
    elif CommonUtils.isFileObject(inputImage):
        openableImage = inputImage
    elif isinstance(inputImage, bytes):
        inputImageLen = len(inputImage)
        openableImage = io.BytesIO(inputImage)

    if openableImage:
        imageFile = Image.open(openableImage)
    elif isinstance(inputImage, Image.Image):
        imageFile = inputImage
    # <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=3543x3543 at 0x1065F7A20>
    imageFile.thumbnail(newSize, resample)
    if outputImageFile:
        # save to file
        imageFile.save(outputImageFile)
        imageFile.close()
    else:
        # save and return binary byte
        imageOutput = io.BytesIO()
        # imageFile.save(imageOutput)
        outputImageFormat = None
        if outputFormat:
            outputImageFormat = outputFormat
        elif imageFile.format:
            outputImageFormat = imageFile.format
        imageFile.save(imageOutput, outputImageFormat)
        imageFile.close()
        compressedImageBytes = imageOutput.getvalue()
        compressedImageLen = len(compressedImageBytes)
        compressRatio = float(compressedImageLen)/float(inputImageLen)
        print("%s -> %s, resize ratio: %d%%" % (inputImageLen, compressedImageLen, int(compressRatio * 100)))
        return compressedImageBytes
```

latest code can found here:

https://github.com/crifan/crifanLibPython/blob/master/python3/crifanLib/thirdParty/crifanPillow.py

Answer (score 3):

JPEG does not support alpha = transparency
So before saving to JPEG discard alpha = transparency

You can check the extension and specifically use covert for JPEG if you work with different formats.

```
extension = str(imgName).split('.')[-1]

if extension == "png":
    bg_image.save(imgName, "PNG")
else:
    if bg_image.mode in ("RGBA", "P"):
        bg_image = bg_image.convert("RGB")
    bg_image.save(imgName, "JPEG")
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced with the same error but after the `quantize()` method.

The solution the same: convert to RGB

`image.quantize(colors=256, method=2).convert('RGB')`