# Using Image (PIL) to save the file marked a difference between 2 pictures

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am comparing 2 pictures and want to mark the difference and save it in a new file.

(Python 2.7 + Windows)

What I am doing is below:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageChops
from PIL import ImageDraw

file1 = 'Animal Nov 2014.jpg'
file2 = ' Animal May 2014.jpg'

im1 = Image.open(file1)
im2 = Image.open(file2)

diff = ImageChops.difference(im1, im2).getbbox()
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im2)
draw.rectangle(diff)
im2.save('file3.jpg')
```

when I save it to 'file3.jpg', it gives error:

```
IOError: cannot write mode P as JPEG
```

when I save it to 'file3.png', it gives error:

```
TypeError: an integer is required
```

How can I have it saved to a new file? Thanks.

---

---

please see the solution at [PIL (Image) ValueError: Not a valid number of quantization tables. Should be between 1 and 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857295/pil-image-valueerror-not-a-valid-number-of-quantization-tables-should-be-bet)

Comment: I can't replicate that error. It saves normally.

Comment: thanks, f.rodrigues. but it just doesn't work me here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer can be found in this thread: [Getting "cannot write mode P as JPEG" while operating on JPG image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21669657/getting-cannot-write-mode-p-as-jpeg-while-operating-on-jpg-image)

> You need to convert the image to RGB mode.

In your case:

```
im2.convert('RGB').save('file3.jpg')
```

Comment: thanks, physicalattraction. but it gives "ValueError: Not a valid number of quantization tables. Should be between 1 and 4."