# Image Conversion - Cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to resize & reduce quality of image before upload in project. Here's what I tried,

```
def save(self):
    im = Image.open(self.image)
    output = BytesIO()
    im = im.resize(240, 240)
    im.save(output, format='JPEG', quality=95)
    output.seek(0)
    self.image = InMemoryUploadedFile(output, 'ImageField', "%s.jpg" % self.image.name.split('.')[0], 'image/jpeg', sys.getsizeof(output), None)
    super(Model, self).save()
```

It's working fine if I upload a `jpg` image but if I upload a `png` or any other image type, it's not working it's raising errors like `cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG` & `cannot write mode P as JPEG` etc.

How can we fix that? Thank You!

Comment: @Teemu Sir, whenever I'm uploading a `jpg` image it's working fine but if I'm uploading any other type of image it's raising an error. How can we change image type to `jpg` so that it can work properly. I'm new here so I've mistakenly added `JavaScript` & `PHP`, I've removed them :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with python, but "cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG" sounds reasonable only with jpg ..?

Comment: @Teemu Sir, this error is occurring when I'm uploading a `png` image

Answer (score 35):

If your image.mode is "P" or "RGBA" and you want to convert it to jpeg then you need to first convert the `image.mode` because the previous modes aren't supported for jpeg

```
if im.mode in ("RGBA", "P"):
    im = im.convert("RGB")
```

https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2609

Answer (score 4):

Summary `timop` and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248405/cannot-write-mode-rgba-as-jpeg/48248432):

- backgroud

  - `JPG` not support `alpha = transparency`
  - `RGBA`, `P` has `alpha = transparency`

    - `RGBA`= `Red Green Blue Alpha`
- result

  - `cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG`
  - `cannot write mode P as JPEG`
- solution

  - before save to JPG, discard `alpha = transparency`

    - such as: convert `Image` to `RGB`
  - then save to `JPG`
- your code

  ```py
  if im.mode == "JPEG":
      im.save(output, format='JPEG', quality=95)
  elif im.mode in ["RGBA", "P"]:
      im = im.convert("RGB")
      im.save(output, format='JPEG', quality=95)
  ```
- More for you:

about `resize & reduce quality of image`, I have implement a function, for you (and others) to refer:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
cfgDefaultImageResample = Image.BICUBIC # Image.LANCZOS

def resizeImage(inputImage,
                newSize,
                resample=cfgDefaultImageResample,
                outputFormat=None,
                outputImageFile=None
                ):
    """
        resize input image
        resize normally means become smaller, reduce size
    :param inputImage: image file object(fp) / filename / binary bytes
    :param newSize: (width, height)
    :param resample: PIL.Image.NEAREST, PIL.Image.BILINEAR, PIL.Image.BICUBIC, or PIL.Image.LANCZOS
        https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.thumbnail
    :param outputFormat: PNG/JPEG/BMP/GIF/TIFF/WebP/..., more refer:
        https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html
        if input image is filename with suffix, can omit this -> will infer from filename suffix
    :param outputImageFile: output image file filename
    :return:
        input image file filename: output resized image to outputImageFile
        input image binary bytes: resized image binary bytes
    """
    openableImage = None
    if isinstance(inputImage, str):
        openableImage = inputImage
    elif CommonUtils.isFileObject(inputImage):
        openableImage = inputImage
    elif isinstance(inputImage, bytes):
        inputImageLen = len(inputImage)
        openableImage = io.BytesIO(inputImage)

    if openableImage:
        imageFile = Image.open(openableImage)
    elif isinstance(inputImage, Image.Image):
        imageFile = inputImage
    # <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=3543x3543 at 0x1065F7A20>
    imageFile.thumbnail(newSize, resample)
    if outputImageFile:
        # save to file
        imageFile.save(outputImageFile)
        imageFile.close()
    else:
        # save and return binary byte
        imageOutput = io.BytesIO()
        # imageFile.save(imageOutput)
        outputImageFormat = None
        if outputFormat:
            outputImageFormat = outputFormat
        elif imageFile.format:
            outputImageFormat = imageFile.format
        imageFile.save(imageOutput, outputImageFormat)
        imageFile.close()
        compressedImageBytes = imageOutput.getvalue()
        compressedImageLen = len(compressedImageBytes)
        compressRatio = float(compressedImageLen)/float(inputImageLen)
        print("%s -> %s, resize ratio: %d%%" % (inputImageLen, compressedImageLen, int(compressRatio * 100)))
        return compressedImageBytes
```

latest code can found here:

https://github.com/crifan/crifanLibPython/blob/master/crifanLib/crifanMultimedia.py