# cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-3.6

I am learning to use 'pillow 5.0' following book 'Automate the boring stuff with python'

The info about the image object

```
In [79]: audacious = auda
In [80]: print(audacious.format, audacious.size, audacious.mode)
PNG (1094, 960) RGBA
```

When I tried to convert filetype, it report error.

```
In [83]: audacious.save('audacious.jpg')
OSError: cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG
```

There's no such a
n error in book.

Comment: the duped answer is not a 100% dupe, but will help you solve the problem - My answer holds the reason you get this error

Comment: I second this. This question refers specifically how to resolve that exception. I ran into this without using PNGs so would not have found it otherwise.

Answer (score 273, accepted):

`JPG` does not support *transparency* - `RGBA` means `Red`, `Green`, `Blue`, `Alpha` - `Alpha` is *transparency*.

You need to discard the `Alpha` Channel or save as something that supports transparency - like `PNG`.

The `Image` class has a method `convert` which can be used to convert `RGBA` to `RGB` - after that you will be able to save as `JPG`.

Have a look here: [the image class doku](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#the-image-class)

```
im = Image.open("audacious.png")
rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
rgb_im.save('audacious.jpg')
```

Adapted from dm2013's answer to [Convert png to jpeg using Pillow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43258974/7505395)

Comment: As @timop suggests [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49255449/849365), a more efficient way is to check whether its in RGBA/P format first before converting to RGB: `if im.mode in ("RGBA", "P"): im = im.convert("RGB")`

Comment: @Prahlad good to do if you do not know you have a RGBA - this question used a RGBA to begin with