# cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG how to resolve this error without converting image format

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have jpg format images and I don't want to convert in png format to resolve this error any other way to resolve this error

```
input_image = Image.open(image_path).convert('RGBA')
txt = Image.new('RGBA', input_image.size, (255, 255, 255, 0))
```

actually i want to create watermark image according to my code i have to compulsory use RGBA mode. please give me solution

**Error : cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG**

Comment: The JPEG format didn't support RGBA, so you can't do it unless you convert to an image file format that does.

Comment: and 'RGB' mode ?? @martineau

Comment: Yes, JPEG does support RGB mode

Comment: i set 'RGB' mode then i get error :image has wrong mode @martineau

Comment: May be it's not the `convert()` call. What kind of image file are you  reading?

Comment: it has str type... image with path

Comment: i edited question if you find out some solution @martineau

Comment: `Image.open()` is used to load an existing image file, i.e. `Image.open("picture.jpg")`. Here's some [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open). The file name extension determines the image file format expected. My question was what kind of image file are you trying to read (and convert)? You don't have any code in your question that is tries to write a file (and the default mode for `open()` is to open the image only for reading).

Comment: The `A` in `RGBA` stands for `alpha` also known as `transparency`. JPEG (Joint **Photographic** Experts Group) does not support transparency because it is for photos and cameras don't normally create transparency layers or photograph transparent things - mainly graphics designers and web designers create transparency layers.

Answer (score 3):

summary [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48206051/image-conversion-cannot-write-mode-rgba-as-jpeg) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248405/cannot-write-mode-rgba-as-jpeg/48248432):

- backgroud

  - `JPG` not support `alpha = transparency`
  - `RGBA`, `P` has `alpha = transparency`

    - `RGBA`= `Red Green Blue Alpha`
- result

  - `cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG`
  - `cannot write mode P as JPEG`
- solution

  - before save to JPG, discard `alpha = transparency`

    - such as: convert `Image` to `RGB`
  - then save to `JPG`
- your code

```py
input_image = Image.open(image_path).convert('RGB')
txt = Image.new('RGB', input_image.size, (255, 255, 255, 0))
```